# How do I count children processes that end successfully?

Tags: c

I want to write a C program that asks the user for an integer and stores it in a variable n. Then, the main process creates two
child processes (both must be children of the main process). One child exits successfully if n>10 and unsuccessfully
otherwise, whereas the other child exits successfully if n>20 and unsuccessfully otherwise. The main process must print
how many of its children ended successfully.

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (void)
{

int n;

printf("Give me a number: ");

scanf("%d", &n);
```

pid_t child_a, child_b;

```
child_a = fork();

if (child_a == 0) {


         if (n>10) {
                exit(1)
         }else{
                exit(0)
        }
} else {


child_b = fork();

if (child_b == 0) {
        if (n>20){
                exit(1)
        }else{
                exit(0)
}
    } else {
        /* Parent Code */
    }
}





}
```

But how do I count how many child processes end successfully?

Comment: I recommend you [read a tutorial on *signals*](https://lasr.cs.ucla.edu/vahab/resources/signals.html), or perhaps a couple of them. When you can handle signals in general and understand the concept, do a search for the `SIGCHLD` signal, and read about it. That way you can count the number of children that exist if the number of `fork` call is not deterministic. However in your case it *is*. You start *two* child processes, and that's it. That means you could [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for each child process to exit, and through that call get the exit status

Comment: The `printf()` statement is woefully botched; it won't compile.  It's hard to tell what you have in mind.  You can loop and collect the dead bodies of the children.  For example: `int count = 0; int corpse; int status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0) { printf("PID %d status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status); if (status == 0) count++; }` — etc.  Print more information; it will help you understand (if you do it sensibly).

Comment: Pasted it wrong should be fixed now.

Comment: Ignore anyone's advice about signals.  You do not need to know anything about signals to do this.  Read documentation on `wait`

Comment: Why are you using `scanf`?  Do *not* read the parameter from stdin.  It makes far more sense to take it as a command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `wait()` command, system call `wait()` function blocks the calling process until one of its child processes exits or a signal is received.

```
int status;
pid_t pid = wait(&status);
printf("Exit = %d, child = %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status), pid);
```

see example at:

[fork() and wait() with two child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708477/fork-and-wait-with-two-child-processes)

and 2nd example using wait() and WEXITSTATUS()

[Linux fork() and wait()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431386/linux-fork-and-wait)

Also more about what happen with multiple cores scheduling of processes:

[fork() and wait() calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242722/fork-and-wait-calls)

Comment: Please note that `WEXITSTATUS` shall only be used if `WEXITED` evaluated to true. Please see the docs here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html